# When I implement the decidePolicyForNavigationAction delegate methond,the Post request will be invalid in WKWebView

Tags: ios, post, uiwebview, wkwebview

my system version is iOS 11.2.6 but i think in higher version have the same appearance.
i post a request in wkwebview like this and it works fine

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.url]];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = [postStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc]initWithFrame:rectDown];
    webview.frame = self.view.frame;
    [webview loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
```

but if i implement the decidePolicyForNavigationAction delegate method like down,the nodejs server can't receive any post data

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction: 
  (WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^) 
  (WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler{
       decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
  }
```

and I want to reuse a wkwebview object anyone have a good idea?

additional i found that when i first load the post request and back then reload and back again reload again it's always works right ,but if I reuse the wkwebview load any other url like google then it can't load the post request anymore.if if don't implement the delegate decidePolicyForNavigationAction method ,it will always works fine.
so ,this is a conflict between decidePolicyForNavigationAction and a reuse wkwebview?

I use this code to format the reuse wkwebview when the wkwebview's controller is remove

```
-(void)webFormat{
    if (@available(iOS 9.0,*)) {
        NSSet *websiteDataTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:WKWebsiteDataTypeDiskCache,
                                   WKWebsiteDataTypeOfflineWebApplicationCache,
                                   WKWebsiteDataTypeMemoryCache,
                                   nil];

//        NSSet *websiteDataTypes = [WKWebsiteDataStore allWebsiteDataTypes];
        NSDate *dateFrom = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];

        [[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] removeDataOfTypes:websiteDataTypes modifiedSince:dateFrom completionHandler:^{

        }];
    }

    [self.configuration.userContentController removeScriptMessageHandlerForName:kScriptHandlerName];
    [self.configuration.userContentController removeAllUserScripts];

    [self stopLoading];
    [self loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]]; 

    self.scrollView.delegate = nil;
    [self setUIDelegate:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by add code

```
self.navigationDelegate = nil
```

in webFormat function .Even when the function webFormat run ,self.navigationDelegate is nil already;I thought that when the viewController remove,as the navigationDelegate of wkwebview ,left something in the corner and influence the webview's next load.who knows.